# syncing two oracle tables with the same structure in different schemas

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

i have users table in schema A and the same one in schema B .
my application is connected to schema A , so the new data is being added in the table in schema A .
what i need to do is to write a procedure with a job so it brings the new rows every night to the table in schema B.
i am confused what to use ,although i have seen multiple ways like cursor or merge or update and insert.

so what is the best solution for my case?

i thought like this :

```
update db.B.users
 set{
      db.B.users.Id = db.A.Id,
      db.B.users.name= db.A.name,
        ....}
 from A
    JOIN B ,A on db.B.users.Id = db.A.Id
```

And then insert the different records into B table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `MERGE` statement for your requirement would look somewhat like this.

I assume that `users.Id` is unique in your table A.

```
MERGE INTO schemaB.users b 
USING schemaA.users a
     ON ( a.Id = b.ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
 SET b.name = a.name,  --Don't update ID( you can't )
     b.othercolumn = a.column
    --all other columns
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
     id,
     name,
     othercolumns ) VALUES (
     a.id,
     a.name,
     a.othercolumns );
```